# Getting params from redirected request

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to redirect the user using this code:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application', array(
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action' => 'connexion',
                    null,
                    array('e' => 'n'),
                ));
```

And getting from the layout the content of the `e` param this way:

```
$_REQUEST['e']
```

But doing that I don't catch anything. How do I to get it please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $this->params()->fromRoute('e', 0); in controller

Comment: @Notuser, I'm trying to deal that from the view

Comment: you can either send it from controller or create your own view helper

Comment: @Marius.C, I'm sending the param from controller to the view.

Comment: @Marius.C, it's not working too. I've just test that from the view using `die(print($this->e));`. I've already tested `$_REQUEST["e"]`, `$this->e`, and `$e`.

Comment: @user3821280 Then you are not sending the var correctly to the view. place a `print_r()` in your controller before sending to view. If that does not work, make a pastebin or paste here your code with the route config for this controller/action and the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Matched Route params in view :

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()
    ->getServiceLocator()
    ->get('Application')
    ->getMvcEvent()
    ->getRouteMatch()
    ->getParams()
```

Request Query/Post in view :

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()
->getServiceLocator()
->get('Request')
->getQuery()->toArray()

$this->getHelperPluginManager()
->getServiceLocator()
->get('Request')
->getPost()->toArray()
```

Comment: that wouldn't work, is there any previous config that you require?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments of your question, the way to go is: `$this->params()->fromRoute();` mentioned by @Notuser. Will use it in a simple example for your use as you're passing the parameters to the view.

```
class ExampleController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function rerouteAction()
    {
        // Notice that 'param' is a route within our route.config.php and in there we
        // define the controller and action, so we do not need to set the controller
        // and action in the redirect. So param now points to paramAction of ExampleController.
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('param', array('e' => 'n'));
    }

    public function paramAction()
    {
        // Leaving fromRoute() blank will return all params!
        $params = $this->params()->fromRoute();
        $e = $params['e'];
        return array('e' => $e);
    }
}
```

So in your view.phtml you can now easily do `<?php echo $this->e; ?>` which should contain: `n`.

The `route.config` of the above example will look something like this:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'reroute' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => 'reroute',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\ExampleController',
                        'action' => 'reroute'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'param' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => 'param',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\ExampleController',
                        'action' => 'param'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```